# Reading character by character from a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I wrote the following program :

```
int main(){
    char str[500],c;
    FILE *f1=fopen("input.txt","r");
    FILE *f2=fopen("output.txt","w");


    while(c=fgetc(f1)!=EOF)
    fputc(toupper(c),f2);


    fclose(f1);
}
```

I was not getting the desired result though.
I rewrote the code using a do while loop.

```
int main(){
  char str[500];
  FILE *f1=fopen("input.txt","r");
  FILE *f2=fopen("output.txt","w");
  char c;

  do
  {
    fputc(toupper(c),f2);
    c=fgetc(f1);
  }while(c!=EOF);
}
```

I figured out that the reason the first code fails is because in the while loop
`while(c=fgetc(f1)!=EOF)`, we cannot guarantee that the left part of `!=` is evaluated first and hence the results are not proper. Is this correct the explanation?

Comment: Your mistake: `c` must be `int` bacause `EOF == -1`. Explanation incorrect.

Comment: Note that on the first pass through the `do { ... } while (...);` loop, `c` is not initialized when a value is printed.  This is not good.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are correct; in your first code your while loop is written wrongly:

```
while(c=fgetc(f1)!=EOF)
```

Should be:

```
while((c=fgetc(f1))!=EOF)
//    ^           ^   added parenthesis
```

Because the [precedence of operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `!=` is greater than `=` operator in conditional expression `c=fgetc(f1)!=EOF`,  the first returned the result of comparing the value from `fgetc()`  with EOF  (either 0 or 1) and assigned that to `c`. (That means simply `c=fgetc(f1)!=EOF` expression is equivalent to `c=(fgetc(f1)!=EOF)` and this is not what you need.)

You need `()` to overwrite precedence as I suggested.

But you have second thing to improve that is `c` variable **must** be an `int` (**not** `char`) in order to hold an EOF-value.

A very good Read: [Definition of EOF and how to use it effectively](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1048865140)

Comment: @user2549925 your welcome! consider Eddy_Em's answer also he has suggested some good flags.

Comment: @user2549925 You may like to accept an answer, as you are new user read: [How accepting answer works?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

I will add a little why `c` should be `int`, not `char`. Suppose you write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    FILE *f1=fopen("input.txt","r");
    FILE *f2=fopen("output.txt","w");
    char c;

    while(EOF != (c=fgetc(f1))){
        if(isalpha(c)) c = toupper(c);
        fputc(c,f2);
    }
return 0;
}
```

And your `input.txt` is

```
some text
Некоторый текст
Ъ - on this letter program will stop
```

in KOI8-R symbol `Ъ` have code 255 == -1 (when you use `char`).
That's why in case of using `char` instead of `int` will give your `output.txt` with only that text:

```
SOME TEXT
НЕКОТОРЫЙ ТЕКСТ
```

As for non-working code with parentheses: `c=fgetc(f1)!=EOF` could be denote by compiler as `c = (fgetc(f1)!=EOF)`, that's why it's better always to add parentheses.

I recommend you to use flags `-Wall -Werror` when compiling your applications. In that case "forgetting" of parentheses would give you an error:

```
11.c: In function 'main':
11.c:9:2: error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```